# What am I doing wrong here?(Python)

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    def count(sequence, item):
        found = 0
        for i in sequence:
            if i == item:
                found += 1
        return (found)
    def removeItemFromArray(sequence, item):
        n = []
        for i in sequence:
            if i != item:
                n.append(i)
        return (n)
    def isIncreasing(sequence):
        if sorted(sequence) == sequence:
            return (True)
        else:
            return (False)
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(sequence) - 1):
        if sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1]:
            count += 1
    for i in sequence:
        sr = removeItemFromArray(sequence, i)
        if (count(sequence, i) == 1 and count == 1 and isIncreasing(sr) == True) or (len(sequence) == 2 and count(sequence, i) == 2):
            return (True)
    else:
        return (False)
print (almostIncreasingSequence([1,3,2,1]))
```

And here is my error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/almostincreasingsequence.py", line 29, in 
>           print (almostIncreasingSequence([1,3,2,1]))
>         File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/almostincreasingsequence.py", line 25, in almostIncreasingSequence
>           if (count(sequence, i) == 1 and count == 1 and isIncreasing(sr) == True) or (len(sequence) == 2 and count(sequence, i) == 2):
>       TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create an [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You have both a function and a variable named `count`.  You're going to have to rename one of them.